# Code is not working, (DHT11 Data to LCD) (Micro:bit) (ERROR: line 3 syntax error can't assign to expression)

Tags: python

This code will not cunction for aome reason and displays  (ERROR: line 3 syntax error can't assign to expression

```
#
from I2C_LCD1602_Class import I2C_LCD1602
LCD1620[0] = I2C_LCD1602_Class(0x27)
while True:
    lcd.puts("temperature:"+str(temperature()), 0, 0)
    lcd.puts("humidity:"+str(humidity()), 2, 0)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        sensor = DHT11(pin0)
        while True:
            try:
                temperature, humidity = sensor.read()
                print("temperature:"+str(temperature)+" C")
                print("humidity:"+str(humidity)+"%")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error : " + str(e))
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Could you please format the code on line 3 and 4 correctly, this is formatted as  text which is difficult to understand because we can't see the indentation.

Comment: I don't know how, I'm new to code

Comment: I tried to make the edit but for some reason stack overflow won't submit it. pleas cut out the whole code section than remove the indentation paste all of it as normal text and then select it and click on the button with the curly braces.

Comment: Done! Feel free to edit now!

Comment: Are you changing the question as you go, asking a new question for each error which comes up? You should invest some time in understanding your own code, search for answers on the Internet and ask questions when other options are exhausted. SO is no a free debugging service. It is a Q&A site.

Comment: When....Wh-wh-when did

Comment: I-I ASK hun like bruh I did as much as a I can myself here

Comment: Also No Im not changing thw question as I go

Answer (score 0):

Your first while loop ends with a "greater than" symbol instead of a colon.
Change `while True>` to `while True:`

Answer (score 0):

You've got

```
LCD1620(0) = I2C_LCD1602_Class(0x27)
```

in line three where you first make a function call, and then try to assign a value to that function call. You can't do this. Maybe you meant

```
LCD1620[0] = I2C_LCD1602_Class(0x27)
```

edit: btw you've also got syntax errors on line four (as mentioned in another answer) and line 6

Comment: Now i got line 2 error no module named I2C_LCD1602_Class

Comment: @VoyagerBudgie that error pretty much means what it says ;-) you don't have the module installed from which you are trying to import something. Might be that the files are in the wrong location, or that you've made a typo or something like that.

Comment: I do have a file under that name and no typo